# Using "new" multiple times on the same pointer

Tags: c++

What happens when I do something like

```
   int * ptr = new int; 
   *ptr = 5;
   // ... do some stuff here
   ptr = new int; 
   // ... reuse ptr to do some other stuff
```

as opposed to

```
   int * ptr1 = new int; 
   *ptr1 = 5;
   // ... do some stuff here
   delete ptr1;
   int * ptr2 = new int; 
   // ... use ptr2 now
```

????

Does the same thing happen at the hardware level? In other words, in the first case, does `ptr = new int;` move on from its previous pointer/value pair, and what happens to those old values? Do they get replaced, do they just float around somewhere, etc.?

Comment: If you don't call "delete", you get a memory leak (1 int).  Use C++ idioms and std::unique_ptr<T> or std::shared_ptr<T>, then the memory will be released automatically.

Comment: The first example just leaks memory.  The memory allocated for the first call to `new` is lost

Comment: @CharlesSalvia But what happens when it is "lost"? What happens to it as far as my operating system is concerned?

Comment: The OS has allocated space for an "int" on its memory heap.  It then allocates space for another integer on its memory heap.  So it's not "lost" so much as your variable, ptr is now pointing to a different bit of memory.  You have two allocations of memory but alas, you have no (easy) way to get a pointer to the first one you allocated.  And that's called a memory leak.

Comment: I would say that a memory leak IS lost, in the sense that your program has allocated memory which it can't deallocate.  If it keeps leaking memory, the program's memory footprint will increase, and eventually the performance of the program, as well as the whole machine, will suffer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `int *ptr` is just a variable that stores an address, nothing more.

After your first `int * ptr = new int;`, it contains the address to a dynamically allocated integer. After your second `int * ptr = new int;`, it contains the address to *another* dynamically allocated integer.

What happens then is nothing special, the only thing is that you didn't call `delete` so the memory allocated for the first integer will never be freed. There's nothing to keep track of it, its address isn't stored anywhere, and so it will keep being useless allocated space until the program ends.

Comment: "until the program ends" - that's assuming you are using an operating system in which ending a process allows all of its allocation to be reclaimed by the OS

Comment: All major OS post 2000 do, I think

Comment: one modern counterexample would be a Windows DLL: it can be Loaded and Unloaded an arbitrary number of times by one process, so if your code leaks memory then this may build up over time (if the process never ends, there is not a separate heap for the DLL so the memory cannot be reclaimed).

Answer (score 7):

In the first example, the pointer is overwritten, but the object it pointed to still exists and is "floating around" somewhere.  This causes [memory leaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

If this happens in a frequently used function or in a loop, you could easily exhaust your memory, storing values that you can't nor won't access any more.

Leaking is in fact a very common error.  A [good practice](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#memory-leaks) is to avoid it by using smart pointers such as [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr). These keep track of a usage count, and free the object automatically if it's no longer used.  For example:

```
 shared_ptr<int> ptr = make_shared<int>();   // allocate an int
 *ptr = 5;
 // ... do some stuff here
 ptr = make_shared<int>();  // the old object is no longer used so deleted automatically
 // ... reuse ptr to do some other stuff
```

Comment: Would this also work when using std::unique_ptrs and std::make_unique? Or is reference counting a requirement for this to work?

Comment: @AdrianKoch this works of course also with [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The difference is that you cannot copy a unique_ptr